# python check required kwargs in a function

Tags: python

I just want to check that the required kwargs must be sent to the function:

```
def myfunca()
    kwargs = {'a'=1, 'b'=2}
    anyfunc(**kwargs)
    return

def anyfunc(**kwargs):

    check_kwargs(**kwargs)    

    print kwargs['a']
    print kwargs['c']
    total = kwargs['a'] + kwargs['c']
    return 


def check_kwargs(**kwargs):
    check if the kwargs required anyfunc is provided from myfunc() 
    if there is not required kwargs for anyfunc then raise appropriate errors
```

Need suggestion

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: `raise appropriate errors` is fairly ambigous - for me, `KeyError` (so simple EAFP approach) if perfectly fine "appropriate error".

Answer (score 0):

Use `assert`. For example,

```
def check_kwargs(kwargdict, requiredargs):
    for r in requiredargs:
        assert r in kwargdict.keys()
```

`requiredargs` would be an iterable containing the names of the arguments that need to be present. You should also remove the `**` from your call to `check_kwargs` as that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: requiredargs shoud i provide it manually ? because I want to use check_kwargs in any function to check the kwargs..

Comment: @gamer, Ok, I see the problem. As far as I know you can't enforce a signature just based on the method body. You could look into the methods in Python's `inspect` module, as well as the `Signature` and `Parameter` classes.